# Call function in List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, list-comprehension

Here I have a function

```
def celToFah(x):
    ftemps = []
    for i in x:
        ftemps.append((9/5 * i) + 32)
    return ftemps
```

where I call it in the list comprehension.

```
ctemps = [17, 22, 18, 19]

ftemps = [celToFah(c) for c in ctemps]
```

getting the following error

**'int' object is not iterable**

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: Because you are passing an `int` to `celToFah`. In `celToFah` you iterate over the argument `x` with a for-loop (the one that has been passed an `int`). You cannot iterate over `int` objects. This is what the error is telling you.

Comment: What output are you looking to get?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`celToFah` is expecting a list, you are giving it an `int`.

Either change `celToFah` to just work on `int`s like so:

```
def celToFah(x):
    return 9/5 * x + 32

ctemps = [17, 22, 18, 19]
ftemps = [celToFah(c) for c in ctemps]
```

Or pass `ctemps` directly into `celToFah`:

```
def celToFah(x):
    ftemps = []
    for i in x:
        ftemps.append((9/5 * i) + 32)
    return ftemps

ctemps = [17, 22, 18, 19]
ftemps = celToFah(ctemps)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was not aware that I was passing an int to the function!